# is there anyway to get Hyperlink content from resource file in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, hyperlink

Is there anyway to get hyperlink content from resource file in xaml. I know there is way on back hand code. I have tried using Name="{x:Static Properties:Resources.stringname}" but it throws error

Or if there is any work around?

I have tried Name but it gives an error:Not able to bind to Uid or Name property in XAML

Comment: Please delete the question or post a proper answer (not inside the question) which explains how to do it & accept that.

Comment: I have changed my question H.B. Thnx for pointing out

Comment: Your question, title, and description as it stands does not make sense. Are you trying to get a URL from a resource file?

Comment: I m just trying to get hyperlink content from resource file. And I think that is what in title as well and my description.

Comment: I guess I was confused by your sample code, which has nothing to do with a URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{x:Static Properties:Resources.SomeUrl}">
    <Run Text="{x:Static Properties:Resources.SomeUrl_Description}"/>
</Hyperlink>
```

Comment: Yeah I guess it didn't click me to use run inside hyperlink. I was just using straight hyperlink and there was no way to localize it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind to the `Name` in XAML since it is being used internally to create references and it needs to be unique. Some relevant bits [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx):

> Name is one of the very few dependency properties that cannot be animated (IsAnimationProhibited is true in metadata), because the name itself is vital for targeting an animation. Data binding a Name is technically possible, but is an extremely uncommon scenario because a data-bound Name cannot serve the main intended purpose of the property: to provide an identifier connection point for code-behind.

> Names must be unique within a namescope. For more information, see WPF XAML Namescopes.